# Extract age from a string-python

Tags: python, regex

Consider this string:

```
s="""A25-54 plus affinities targeting,Demo (AA F21-54),
A25-49 Artist Affinity Targeting,M21-49 plus,plus plus A 21+ targeting"""
```

I am looking to fix my pattern which currently does not pull all the age groups in the string (`A 21+` is missing from the current output).

Current try:

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?:A|A |AA F|M)(\d+-\d+)',s)
```

Output:

```
['25-54', '21-54', '25-49', '21-49'] #doesnot capture the last group A 21+
```

Expected Output:

```
['A25-54','AA F21-54','A25-49','M21-49','A 21+']
```

As you see, I would like to have the last group too which is `A 21+` which is currently missing from my output.

Also if I can get the string associated with the capture group. presently my output apart from not capturing all the groups doesnt have the string before the age group. eg: I want `'A25-54` instead of `'25-54'` , i guess because of `?:` .

Appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing part of the match is due to the fact your pattern contains one capturing group and once there is a capturing group in the regex, the `re.findall` only returns that parts. The second issue is that you should match either `-` followed with 1 or more digits *or* a literal `+` symbol after the first one or more digits are matched.

You may use

```
(?:A|A |AA F|M)\d+(?:-\d+|\+)
```

*NOTE*: You might want to add a word boundary at the start to only match those `A`, `AA F`, etc. as whole words: `r'\b(?:A|A |AA F|M)\d+(?:-\d+|\+)'`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FzRVGn/1/) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3AA%7CA%20%7CAA%20F%7CM)%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A-%5Cd%2B%7C%5C%2B)):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:A|A |AA F|M)` - a non-capturing group matching `A`, `A` , `AA` , `AA F` or `M`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:-\d+|\+)` - a non-capturing group matching `-` and 1+ digits after it or a single `+` symbol.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/PAi6wv):

```
import re
s="""A25-54 plus affinities targeting,Demo (AA F21-54),
A25-49 Artist Affinity Targeting,M21-49 plus,plus plus A 21+ targeting"""
print(re.findall(r'(?:A|A |AA F|M)\d+(?:-\d+|\+)',s))
# => ['A25-54', 'AA F21-54', 'A25-49', 'M21-49', 'A 21+']
```

Comment: FYI: You may contract the first group further as `(?:A(?: |A F)?|M)\d+(?:-\d+|\+)`. It is less readable but it follows the best practices: each alternative inside a group should not match at the same location as other groups.